# Display values of multiple input type range in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display values of every slider I have on my page, this is my code so far:

```js
var i = 0;
var st = 'slider';
var ot = 'output';
var s = '';
var o = '';

for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
i++;
s = st+i;
o = ot+i;

 var s = document.getElementById("range"+i);
    var o = document.getElementById("limit"+i);
 o.innerHTML = s.value;
 
s.oninput = function() {
 o.innerHTML = this.value;
}

}
```

```html
<div id="slidecontainer">
     <input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="20" class="slider" id="range1" >
 <label>You chose <span id="limit1"></span></label>
</div>

<div id="slidecontainer">
     <input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="20" class="slider" id="range2" >
 <label>You chose <span id="limit2"></span></label>
</div>

<div id="slidecontainer">
     <input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="20" class="slider" id="range3" >
 <label>You chose <span id="limit3"></span></label>
</div>
```

It's only changing the last value when I move any slider, I want to display the value of each slider respectively. I'm using a loop in my JavaScript code because I have more than 20 sliders and I don't want to write a function for each of them unless that is the only way of doing it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is related to variable scope. There is only one variable named `o`, each iteration of the loop changes this variable. So when the 
`oninput` function is evaluated `o` equals the last value you set it to equal. The current value of `o` is not "saved" in the function definition.

See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for more information.

See solution below, here I find the `limit` in each call to the function.

```js
function updateLabel() {
  var limit = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("limit")[0];
  limit.innerHTML = this.value;
}

var slideContainers = document.getElementsByClassName("slidecontainer");

for (var i = 0; i < slideContainers.length; i++) {
  var slider = slideContainers[i].getElementsByClassName("slider")[0];
  updateLabel.call(slider);
  slider.oninput = updateLabel;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="20" class="slider">
  <label>You chose <span class="limit"></span></label>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="20" class="slider">
  <label>You chose <span class="limit"></span></label>
</div>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="2" max="50" value="20" class="slider">
  <label>You chose <span class="limit"></span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution, works great now! thank you very much.